# why this jQuery animation loop doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, jquery-animate

```
<script>
function swim() {

    $("#ship").animate({left: "-=-540px"}, 3000, function() {

        $("#ship").css("-moz-transform", "scaleX(-1)");
        $("#ship").css("-o-transform", "scaleX(-1)");
        $("#ship").css("-webkit-transform", "scaleX(-1)");
        $("#ship").css("transform", "scaleX(-1)");
        $("#ship").css("filter", "FlipH");
        $("#ship").css("-ms-filter", "FlipH");
        $("#ship").animate({left: "-=540px"}, 3000);
        swim();

        })

    }


    swim();

</script>
```

When I use only `document.ready` works fine, but stops after an attempt to turn it to a loop. There must be a syntax bug somewhere but I can't figure out where.

EDIT: nvm. It was the case of putting the script to `<head>` instead of `<body>`.

Comment: if `function(){}` you can use `this` insead of repeating query.

Comment: missing semicolon at end of $("#ship").... statement. what I don't think that might be the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a reason why it needs the document ready wrapper. A "normal" function isn't an equal replacement for it. If you call the function before the DOM is ready, the `#ship` selector doesn't match anything, the animation doesn't run, and the callback isn't executed.

Call the function in a document ready event:

```
$( swim );
```